# Django Session Auth and DRF Knox JWT

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API from which users can login to get a token so they can make requests, etc and I have also made a a session login as there are a few scenarios where I need the user session token. Now if a user logs in to the API and afterwards they need to login using the session Auth its all good however the reverse does not work. If you are logged in using session Auth and then want to login via the API to release a token I get a response of Forbidden. Could someone please offer some insight?